# Unbound local variable Python 3.2

Tags: python, try-catch

This error pops up randomly, and I'm pretty sure it's because the infoGotten variable isn't initialized before the return statement calls it. The part that has me puzzled is how it's getting to that part of the code to produce that error in the first place. Hopefully someone can explain to me why that is as I haven't been able to figure it out yet. I'm guessing it's because of the try/except statement but I did some searching and checked 7.4 in the manual and it doesn't appear (to me anyways) that I'm doing something incorrect.

```
breakLoop = 0
def get_item_info(linkParameters):
    global breakLoop
    nheaders = {'User-Agent' : 'Firefox/15.0.1'}
    purl = 'http://example.com/something.php'
    pd = linkParameters
    nreq = urllib.request.Request(purl, pd, nheaders)
    if breakLoop >= 4:
        return 'Request timed out {} times'.format(breakLoop)
    try:
        nresponse = urllib.request.urlopen(nreq)
    except urllib.error.URLError:
        breakLoop += 1
        get_item_info(pd)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
        breakLoop += 1
        get_item_info(pd)        
    else:
        infoGotten = nresponse.read()
    return infoGotten
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the error you are seeing, can you post it?

Comment: Please show the complete traceback when asking about errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the results of the recursive calls, so it should be `return get_item_info(pd)` in the `except` clauses (which I combined below):

```
breakLoop = 0
def get_item_info(linkParameters):
    nheaders = {'User-Agent' : 'Firefox/15.0.1'}
    purl = 'http://example.com/something.php'
    pd = linkParameters
    nreq = urllib.request.Request(purl, pd, nheaders)
    if breakLoop >= 4:
        return 'Request timed out {} times'.format(breakLoop)
    try:
        nresponse = urllib.request.urlopen(nreq)
    except (urllib.error.URLError, urllib.error.HTTPError):
        breakLoop += 1
        return get_item_info(pd)
    else:   
        return nresponse.read()
```

Recursion seems like a weird way to perform the retries though, why not use a loop?  The following seems more clear:

```
def get_item_info(linkParameters):
    nheaders = {'User-Agent' : 'Firefox/15.0.1'}
    purl = 'http://example.com/something.php'
    pd = linkParameters
    for i in range(5):
        nreq = urllib.request.Request(purl, pd, nheaders)
        try:
            nresponse = urllib.request.urlopen(nreq)
            return nresponse.read()
        except (urllib.error.URLError, urllib.error.HTTPError):
            pass
    return 'Request timed out 4 times'
```

Comment: we can also use `except urllib.error.URLError and urllib.error.HTTPError`, no need of two `except` which are doing same thing.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I'm pretty sure it's spelled `except (urllib.error.URLError, urllib.error.HTTPError)` (no `and`).

Comment: Thanks guys! I used recursion for the retries simply because it never crossed my mind to make a for loop instead. Well, at least I now know that I have to use return with recursion loops. The more you know!

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Your example works by chance because (1) the `except` clause accepts any expression, (2) exceptions (like most things) evaluate as true, (3) `True and foo` returns `foo` and (4) the exception that is actually raised is the one you name last. Tricky? Perhaps, but I don't know where you even got that idea. Every resource I've seen is very clear on this. Counter examples: http://ideone.com/mp1aE and http://ideone.com/go3Qo